# Why am I getting an SSL unsupported protocol error for Git?

Tags: git

I'm receiving the following error when using Sourcetree and the Git command line on Windows.

```
`fatal: unable to access 'https://xxx.git.beanstalkapp.com/myRepo.git/': error:1425F102:SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol`
```

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling. I've also remade my SSH keys several times. I'm unable to pull/push anything from Beanstalk. I can't find anything online either.

Any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: The problem is not with SSH but with SSL protocol. Perhaps outdated version of OpenSSL. Time to upgrade git.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I did download the new version of Git and uninstalled the old version. Are there certain params I need to set it up with when installing?

Comment: I don't think so. Just in case verify you don't have [`http.ssl*`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-httpsslVersion) settings in your git config files.

Comment: @phd what should those settings be for the http.ssl?

Answer (score 0):

I opened my `.gitconfig` file and had to remove all of the following:

```
 [http]
 sslVersion = tlsv1.0
 sslVersion = tlsv1.1
 sslVersion = tlsv1.2
 sslVerify = false
```

Not sure why it doesn't like that. But this worked for me to push to Beanstalk.